# Detect tap outside tableview cells to perform action

Tags: ios, tableview

I am new to iOS development, i've been following apple intro to iOS and implemented the to-do list app.

I have tableview that shows the list of the current to-do list, and another view controller that allows the user to add a new item in a textfield then add to the list.
I have a little + on top of my tableview that performs a segue action to the add to-do item view.

I want to be able to perform the same action if the user taps on an empty cell
I tried to put this code in and it works but I want to put it in the right position so it only triggers when the user hits empty space in the table:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showAddItem" sender:self];
```

Thank you.

`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"ListPrototypeCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    // Configure the cell...
    ABCTodoItem *toDoItem = [self.toDoItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = toDoItem.itemName;
    if (toDoItem.completed) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    return cell;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see at least two solutions here.

**Solution 1. Adding en empty cell by modifying the data source**

After you have populated your **toDoItems** add this:

```
[self.toDoItems addObject:@""];
```

Notice that **toDoItems** should be type of NSMutableArray.

Now let's handle creating cells:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"ListPrototypeCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSObject *objItem = [self.toDoItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if([objItem isKindOfClass: [ABCTodoItem class]]) {
     ABCTodoItem *toDoItem = (ABCTodoItem*) objItem;
     cell.textLabel.text = toDoItem.itemName;
}
else if([objItem isKindOfClass: [NSString class]]) {
     NSString *item = (NSString*) objItem;
     cell.textLabel.text = item;
}
return cell;
}
```

Touch action:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   NSObject *objItem = [self.toDoItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   if([objItem isKindOfClass: [ABCTodoItem class]]) {
      ABCTodoItem *toDoItem = (ABCTodoItem*) objItem;
     // Open your toDoItem

   }
   else if([objItem isKindOfClass: [NSString class]]) {

       self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showAddItem" sender:self];
   }

}
```

**Solution 2. Adding an empty cell without modifying the data source**

This makes it possible to create one extra cell:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     return [self.toDoItems count] + 1;
}
```

Now again let's handle creating cells:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"ListPrototypeCell";
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

if([indexPath.row < [self.toDoItems count]) {
   NSObject *objItem = [self.toDoItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

   if([objItem isKindOfClass: [ABCTodoItem class]]) {
      ABCTodoItem *toDoItem = (ABCTodoItem*) objItem;
      cell.textLabel.text = toDoItem.itemName;
   }
}
else {

      cell.textLabel.text = @"";
}
return cell;
}
```

And then handling the touch action:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  if([indexPath.row < [self.toDoItems count]) {
     NSObject *objItem = [self.toDoItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

     if([objItem isKindOfClass: [ABCTodoItem class]]) {
        ABCTodoItem *toDoItem = (ABCTodoItem*) objItem;
        // Open your toDoItem
     }
  }
  else {
     self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showAddItem" sender:self];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion this solution is the cleanest:

Add a tap gesture to your `UITableView`'s `backgroundView`. If the `backgroundView` is `nil`, add a transparent `UIView`, and add a gesture to it.

Now hook up your action to this gesture recognizer.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I have understood your question correctly; correct me if I am wrong. You have a to-do List populated in a `TableViewController` which has some tasks and one (or more) empty cells. When you click on these cells, you would want to call `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showAddItem" sender:self];` a method that presents a `ViewController` that allows you to add more items into the list.

Once you have populated your `TableViewController` in such a way that you have an empty cell, you can always get the `NSIndexPath` of the empty cell.

When you tap on a cell, a method will be called, called:  `(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`. As you can see, you will get the index information of the tapped cell. There, you can add the code like so:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //Add your logic for the rest of the items

    //If you have 7 items in the to-do list, you would have 8 cell, 
    //the eight one being empty. If indexPath.row is equal to 8 then, 
    //it says that it MUST be the last item, that is empty
    if(indexPath.row == self.itemsInTheList.count) {
          [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showAddItem" sender:self];
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can set the `tag` property of the cell; and that's the story for a different day.

Comment: It didn't work, i know this method triggers when use tap on a tableviewcell, the thing is it feels to me, when i delete all my items from the tablevliew list, and the tableview is empty, it feels like these empty cells are not tappable or doesn't trigger this method anymore..

Comment: There is this that you have to do. You have to set the `self.tableView .delegate = self` and `self.tableView.dataSource = self`.

Comment: And there is a method, `-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section`. Here return one number more than the number of items in the list. Something  like `return self.itemsInTheList.count+1`

And here, `(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` write in such a way that if `indexPath.row == self.itemsInTheList.count` it is empty.

Comment: where do i put that? in the method (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath ?

Comment: It didn't work that way also.. i am sorry i am probably newbie and not sure if i am doing what you tell me correctly

Comment: All right, I will walk you through this. *holds hands*
I assume you have an instance level `UITableView *tableView;`.
In the `viewDidLoad` method, add `tableView.delegate = self` and `tableView.dataSource = self`. Right?

Comment: Right, i have that written. Yet the method still doesn't get me to add to-do item view

Comment: Can you post your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: I did, up in initial question part

Comment: Modify this in such a way that the last cell is always empty.